# How to prevent files in debug/release folder from been deleted?

Tags: c#, git, build, msbuild

We have some binary files that are not generated from code that we ship with our application. They were placed manually in debug/release folder. VS didn't touched those files when compiling the project.
I decided to include those files in repository by placing them in separate project that is added as reference to main project.

This works fine, however I did it on separate "defaultData" branch and when I switch back to the master branch and build my main project the MSBuild (I guess) removes all files that are not referenced in any project, leaving only empty folders. When add the files back manually and rebuild the project on master branch they are not deleted. When I again switch back to "defaultData", build, switch forward to "master" and build - the files are deleted. What is happening?

I tried to investigate this but can't figure it out. I switched `MSBuild  output verbosity` to "Diagnosting" but I can't find any mentions of deleting those file in generated log.

In the past I also had similar, rare issues with single files placed manually in debug/release folder been deleted.

For the files that should be included in application it's not a problem, however I don't want to reference every single file I test in the project.

---

> Are "the files" by chance some .dll and your "repository" excludes them? (for example .gitignore).

No, we don't have any lib files. Those are simply some app configuration files, image assets, example data etc. For external/unmanaged dlls we have another project, but this was done long time ago and we don't have any issues with that.

And to be more clear, in other words. Dose files are not part of repository on "master" branch but only on "defaultData" branch witch was made only for that purpose. I moved debug folder to my desktop, created the branch, added new project, copied needed files, set them as "copy if newer", build the main project and verified that they are indeed placed correctly with new debug folder. So then I switched to "master" branch, build the main project and the files created by "defaultData" are gone. This happens every time. However if I copy the very same files manually, using windows explorer, they are not deleted, this is want bugs me the most.

Also, if the git ignores the whole \bin directory what it has to do with the files been deleted there? The whole procedure is done only on the local PC.

Comment: Are "the files" by chance some `.dll` and your "repository" excludes them? (for example `.gitignore`).

Comment: @pawulon, in general you don't want to put anything in the debug/release folder that is not persisted by the solution. These folders should be able to be deleted without any consequences. If you need files to be deployed when you build you should put them in the solution and indicate they are content that needs to be copied to the deployment directory. Or create a post build action to copy the files to the debug/release folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's git normal behavior when handling 'tracked' files.

If the files are committed in the "defaultData" branch but doesn't exist in 'master' branch, git consider that these files should be removed so it delete them.

The good solution for me is to commit these files in another folder and having a msbuild step during the init phase that copies the files in the output folder.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're witnessing is by design; it's how Git works.

When you switch from one commit to another commit (which is what happens when you switch branches), all untracked (not committed) files are left alone and just sit there, following you around from commit to commit. But if one or both commits is tracking the file, it will create the file when switching from untracked to tracked, and delete the file when switching from tracked to untracked.

The fact that you committed the files on branch `defaultData` means that when switching to that branch, those files will be created if they don't exist, or they will be modified if they do exist and they are different than the committed version. Once you switch off of `defaultData` to any branch or commit where those files are no longer tracked, they will be deleted.

**What can you do?**

Any of these will solve your problem:

1. Commit the files on `master` as well. This could be done by either merging `defaultData` into `master` if it's ready to be merged, or you can find the commit where the files were added on `defaultData` and cherry-pick that commit over to `master`. Once the files are tracked on both branches you'll be able to switch back and forth between them and the files will stay.
2. Delete the files and commit that change to `defaultData`. This will make the files not tracked anymore (presumably anywhere), and then you can add the files back one last time, and from now on they will be untracked everywhere and won't be modified by Git.
3. Stop checking out `defaultData`. Even with the files untracked on `master`, they won't get deleted until you switch to `defaultData` and then switch to another commit/branch again.

**Side Note:** My personal preference is to not track binaries in my Git repo, or at least not the same repo as my code. That would make me lean towards option #2, and I'd probably rebase (if possible) and squash the delete commit into the commit that created them so it appears as if they never existed. From there I'd use a separate artifacts repo or package manager to store the binaries.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but I think you are talking about files in the source directory. I'm not surprised that the files are not present in the source directory on master - this is expected behaviour. My problem is that the files are deleted from output `bin` directory which suppose to be ignored by git, right? And the files are not deleted when  I just do checkout to master, but only when I build the project. Therefore I suspect the issue it not specifically related to git but to MSBuild.

Comment: @Pawcio if the `bin` directory is under the root of the Git repository, then from Git's POV it isn't any different than a source directory or something else. From there, if you add the `bin` directory to the `.gitignore` file, and if the files in that directory are untracked, then Git will not list files in that directory as new or modified when you run `git status`, and it also won't stage files in that directory when you add all files (e.g. `git add .`). As you described, the `bin` directory is untracked on `master`, but tracked on `defaultData`. (cont...)

Comment: @Pawcio If you switch to `master` and the files are deleted, and then you add them back manually, Git won't delete them again and also won't stage them, because they are untracked and ignored from the point of view of the `master` branch. As for VS deleting them, that's possible, if your clean or rebuild steps wipes out the directory in preparation for recreating those files as part of the build. Note that if you see the files there after switching from `defaultData` to `master`, and then you build and they disappear, then it's unrelated to Git. (I would confirm that to be sure.)